# Conditional probability or Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I'm trying to do a question in probability:

''we flip three coins''

''What is the probability that the second coin landed tails, given that two coins
(exactly) landed head?''

I have set out the sample space - S= {HHH, HHT, THH, HTH, HTT, TTH, THT, TTT} 
E1 - tails on the second coin - {HTH}
E2 - outcomes feat. 2 heads exactly - {HHT, HTH, THH}

P(E1 + E2) = 1/8

P(E2) = 3/8

P(E1/E2) = P(E1+E2)/P(E2) =  [(1/8)]/[(3/8)] = 1/3

? Is this correct or will I have to use Bayes' theorem for this?

Comment: No that's correct. Think of the conditioning like restricting your sample space to only {HHT,HTH,THH}. Then you see that only one of the three gives the desired event. But equally going through the motions with conditional probability rule works.

Answer (score 0):

$\color{green}{\checkmark}$ The calculations using Conditional Probability are correct. $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B\mid A)$

- To use Bayes' Theorem you'd need the other conditional probability. $\mathsf P(A\mid B)\;\mathsf P(B)= \mathsf P(B\mid A)\;\mathsf P(A)$

---

Your labeling of the events is a *bit* misleading.

You have:

> the sample space - S= {HHH, HHT, THH, HTH, HTT, TTH, THT, TTT}
>
> E1 - tails on the second coin - {HTH}

No, tails on the second coin is: {HTH, HTT, TTH, TTT}

> E2 - outcomes feat. 2 heads exactly - {HHT, HTH, THH}

And that leads to: E1 $\cap$ E2 : {HTH}  , tails on the second coin *and* exactly two heads.

Which, despite the labelling, you then *have used correctly* in the conditional probability calculation.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(E_1\mid E_2) & = \frac{\mathsf P(E_1\cap E_2)}{\mathsf P(E_2)}
\\ & = \frac{1/8}{3/8}
\\ & = \tfrac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Showing that it was *just* an error in labelling not understanding. But still, try to avoid doing that on an exam.

Comment: I'm confused with the interchange between Bayes' theorem and the 'typical' conditional probability formula - is the 'typical' formula accredited to Baye?

Comment: Well, fair enough. Conditional Probability is defined as, $\;\mathsf P(A\mid B) \mathop{:=} \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\;$, and Bayes' Law is derived from that: $\;\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \frac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}\;$.